# Не записывается ID в sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Не записывается ID в sqlite.
Остальное все записывается, без `create table id not null`, id всегда равен NULL, а хотелось бы, чтобы работал инкремент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу сделать, чтобы через пайтон я вводил данные в sqlite и чтобы у каждого заказа был свой ID, который работает по increment, чтобы сам делал значения. В SQL management studio работает ID INCREMENT, но в Python не работает.

ДБ создана такой командой:

```
CREATE TABLE MainDB(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    username nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    request nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Icount nvarchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я хочу сделать чтобы через пайтон я вводил данные в sqlite и чтобы у каждого заказа был свой ID, который работает по increment чтобы сам делал значения. в SQL managment studio работает ID INCREMENT, но в Python не работает

Comment: Покажите, как создана таблица: `create table ...`

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MainDB](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [username] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [request] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Icount] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)

Comment: `IDENTITY` - это команда Sql Server. В SQLite используйте [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

Comment: Я что-то вообще ничего не понимаю... Management Studio - это оболочка для Sql Server. Тип `nvarchar` тоже используется в Sql Server. / Для работы с SQLite используйте документацию, статьи и книги именно по SQLite. Различия между разными СУБД очень велики.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

# Создать базу и Таблицу   

try:
    con = sqlite3.connect('w.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS   MainDB (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
     username TEXT NOT NULL,
      request TEXT NOT NULL,
       Icount TEXT NOT NULL);''')
    con.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при подключении к sqlite", error)
finally:
    if (con):
        con.close()
        print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
```

#Заполнить данными

```
try:
    x=['myname','blabla','count']
    con = sqlite3.connect('w.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO MainDB(username,request,Icount) VALUES (?,?,?)''',x)
    con.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при подключении к sqlite", error)
finally:
    if (con):
        con.close()
        print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")



# Получить данные   



try:
    con = sqlite3.connect('w.db')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    xx=cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM MainDB''')
    con.commit()
    print(xx.fetchall())
except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при подключении к sqlite", error)
finally:
    if (con):
        con.close()
        print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")


Соединение с SQLite закрыто
Соединение с SQLite закрыто
[(1, 'myname', 'blabla', 'count')]
Соединение с SQLite закрыто
```

Comment: [Datatypes In SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). SQLite хоть и поймёт `nvarchar` и приведёт его к типу `text`, но всё же лучше сразу использовать "родной" тип `text`.

Comment: Да, лучше исправлю на родной, спасибо.